# show $\int_0^{\infty} \frac{x\sin ax}{x^2+t^2}dx = \frac{\pi}{2}e^{-at}$

Tags: integration, measure-theory, definite-integrals

I'm asked to show  $\int_0^{\infty} \frac{x\sin ax}{x^2+t^2}dx = \frac{\pi}{2}e^{-at}$ when $t,a > 0$.
I tried using integration by parts integrating $\frac{x}{x^2+t^2}$. But it seems that $\frac{x\sin ax}{x^2+t^2}$ has no antiderivative. What should I try?

Comment: Trigonometric substitution?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using contour integration or Fourier inversion, one can show that if $a>0$ then
$$ \frac{1}{\pi}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{e^{iax}}{1+x^2}\;dx=e^{-a}$$ which implies that
$$ \frac{2}{\pi}\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{\cos(ax)}{1+x^2}\;dx=e^{-a}$$
if $a>0$. Differentiating with respect to $a$ then yields
$$\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{x\sin(ax)}{1+x^2}\;dx=\frac{\pi}{2}e^{-a}$$
and finally replacing $a$ with $at$ and making a substitution in the integral yields the desired result.

Answer (score 5):

---

> **I thought it might be instructive to present a way forward that relies on real analysis only and forgoes complex analysis.  To that end, we now proceed.**

---

Let $I(a,t)$ be given by

$$\begin{align}
I(a,t)&=\int_0^\infty \frac{x\sin(ax)}{x^2+t^2}\,dx\\\\
&\overbrace{=}^{x\mapsto x|t|}\int_0^\infty \frac{x\sin(a|t|x)}{x^2+1}\,dx\\\\
&=\int_0^\infty \frac{(x^2+1-1)\sin(a|t|x)}{x(x^2+1)}\,dx\\\\
&=\int_0^\infty \frac{\sin(a|t|x)}{x}\,dx-\int_0^\infty \frac{\sin(a|t|x)}{x(x^2+1)}\,dx\\\\
&=\frac\pi2\text{sgn}(a|t|)-\int_0^\infty \frac{\sin(a|t|x)}{x(x^2+1)}\,dx\tag1
\end{align}$$

---

For $|at|>\delta>0$, the integrals $\int_0^\infty \frac{\cos(a|t|x)}{x^2+1}\,dx$ and $\int_0^\infty \frac{x\sin(a|t|x)}{x^2+1}\,dx$ uniformly converge and we may differentiate twice (with respect to $a|t|$) under the integral on the right-hand side of $(1)$ to find for $|at|\ge \delta>0$

$$\frac{d^2I(a,t)}{d(a|t|)^2}=I(a,t)\tag2$$

The general solution to $(2)$ is $I(a,t)=Ae^{-a|t|}+Be^{a|t|}$.  To find the integration constants $A$ and $B$ we invoke the conditions (i) $\lim_{at\to 0^+}I(a,t)=\frac{\pi}{2}$ and $(ii)$ $\left.\left(\frac{dI(a,t)}{d(a|t|)}\right)\right|_{a|t|=0}=-\frac\pi2$.  Proceeding, we find that $A=\frac\pi2$ and $B=0$.

Putting it all together and exploiting the oddness of the integrand around $a$, we find that

$$I(a,t)=\text{sgn}(a)\frac\pi2 e^{-|at|}$$

And we are done!

Comment: This is great!!

Comment: @vonneunann Thank you.  Much appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

By residue theorem, and due to the parity of your integrand, we can write it as

$$\frac{1}{2}\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} \frac{z\Im \left(e^{iaz}\right)}{(z + it)(z-it)}\ dz = \frac{1}{2}\Im\int_{|z|=1} \frac{z\Im \left(e^{iaz}\right)}{(z + it)(z-it)}\ dz$$

$x = +it$ lies in the upper half plane hence by residues formula:

$$\Im \frac{1}{2}2\pi i \lim_{z\to it} (z-it)\frac{z e^{iaz}}{(z+it)(z-it)} = \Im \frac{\pi}{2}i e^{-at}$$

Whence the result

$$\color{red}{\frac{\pi}{2}e^{-at}}$$

Answer (score 0):

Let’s  first evaluate the integral using contour integration along anti-clockwise direction of the path
$$\gamma=\gamma_{1} \cup \gamma_{2} \textrm{ where }  \gamma_{1}(t)=t+i 0(-R \leq t \leq R)  \textrm{ and } \gamma_{2}(t)=R e^{i t}  (0<t<\pi) $$
As $R \rightarrow +\infty$, we have
$$
\begin{aligned}\int_0^{\infty} \frac{\cos (a x)}{x^2+t^2} d x&=\frac{1}{2}\left(\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{e^{a x i}}{x^2+t^2} d z\right) \\
& =\frac{1}{2} \Re \int_\gamma \frac{e^{a zi}}{z^2+t^2} d x \\
& =\frac{1}{2} \Re\left[2 \pi i \operatorname{lim}_{z \rightarrow ti}(z-t i) \frac{e^{a z i}}{z^2+t^2} d z\right] \\
& =\pi \Re\left(i \cdot \frac{e^{a(t i) i}}{2 t i}\right)\\&=\frac{\pi}{2 t} e^{-a t}
\end{aligned}
$$

Differentiating both sides w.r.t. $a$ yields our integral
$$
\boxed{\int_0^{\infty} \frac{x \sin (a x)}{x^2+t^2} d x=\frac{\pi}{2} e^{-a t}}
$$